# What's the meaning of the asterisk when using on the attribute "pattern" of an input?

Tags: html

Here's an example:

```
<input title="Only numbers" pattern="[0-9]*" type="text" />
```

I would like to know what implies using `*` in `pattern="[0-9]*"`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` means 0 or more of the previous item, in this case digits 0-9.

This means the empty string will also be allowed as well as "0", "12" etc..

Other quantifiers exist, like `+` means 1 or more etc...

There are many tutorials out there, but you can't go wrong with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Syntax)

In your case, I'd recommend using the built-in number type instead as the intent is clearer...

```
<input title="Only numbers" type="number" />
```